# Website not coming up only for airtel broadband

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, nameserver, godaddy

We are into a strange issue. We recently launched our website. Domain name is registered with GoDaddy & is hosted on GoDaddy VPS. Website is live & comes up properly everywhere other that Airtel Broadband users.

If we change "DNS server address" from control panel -> network settings to Google DNS (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4), website comes up on Airtel Broadband.

Changing "DNS server address" for my local machine can not be the solution as I want everyone in the world to be able to access our website. What can be the solution?

Comment: The OP needs to speak to Airtel Broadband and get them to fix their DNS.

Comment: Thanks lain for your comments. I'm new here. Might be my question is silly but I don't know what is OP. And what should be told to Airtel Broadband?

Comment: most likely Airtel Broadband is his own internet providers. He's been working with the domain name with old & new setting ; airtel must have the old IP in cache. Waiting for expiry is the normal way of doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All DNS modifications are subject to a timer called a 'TTL' (TimeToLive). It state 'how long should I wait before I ask the server for the NAME->IP translation again'. There's a very high probability that Airtel broadband DNS has the old IP in their cache.

You can see your currently configured TTL by going through a tool like http://www.dnsstuff.com/ and running the DNS report.

Through command line tools such a 'dig' and 'nslookup', there's way to tell what is the timer left at the Airtel Broadband default DNS server ; however, if it is working correctly on the Google DNS, it is most likely only a question of time before the propagation is completed.

If you provides us with the domain name, I can run this TTL check for you.

Comment: 10 minutes for humsaathsaath.com ; 1hrs for www.humsaathsaath.com 

Everything seems ok.

Comment: Website still not coming up on airtel broadband.. Can you provide some more help?

Comment: I've looked at all the Airtel broadband published DNS servers and I don't get any errors / differences. What IP are you using as DNS servers with them ?